# Cannot find details about ReactNativePropRegistry file with RN 0.56

Tags: react-native, native-base

`ReactNativePropRegistry` was in `shims` folder till React Native 0.55.4

This file is missing in 0.56 and no changelog details about this

Comment: I created an RN app with --version="0.54.0" and there is no shims folder or ReactNativePropRegistry